# Image path binding in MVC using knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I wants to display an image in my MVC application using knockoutjs. I am using the following code.
 Javascript (images.js)

```
 function viewModel() {
        this.ImgPath = ko.observable("~/Content/Images/abcd.JPG");
};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

in View,

```
<img data-bind="attr: { src: ImgPath }" />
```

Also I added the following in my view.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/images.js"></script>
```

But image is not displaying in my application. How to bind the image path to view in mvc using knockout?

Comment: The problem would be with `~`, because `~` would be only understand by ASP.Net but not by HTML Give normal path like - `/Content/Images/abcd.JPG` and check. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @ramiramilu : No... Still the problem remains same...

Comment: Did you see any error in F12 Developer Tools of browser? Are you sure that the image exists in the path? i think you need to give - `../Content/Images/abcd.JPG` if your view is in Views folder, then you have to move one level top and then go to the image location.

Comment: While running the application, open a new tab in the browser and check whether <yourdomain.com>/Content/Images/abcd.JPG displays the image. if it does, update the image path to ko.observable("/Content/Images/abcd.JPG");

Comment: Can I post this as answer?

Comment: @ramiramilu : ofcourse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change image path from `"~/Content/Images/abcd.JPG"` to `"/Content/Images/abcd.JPG"`.

`~` will not be understood by HTML and it will not load image. `~` will only be understood by ASP.Net engine.

Answer (score 1):

I made a small change in my code.

```
function viewModel() {
this.ImgPath = ko.observable("/Content/Images/abcd.JPG");
};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

And now its working fine.
 Thanks to all.